# PHP form check if user inputs the correct number

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm a PHP noob but I have a form which is currently working fine, but I want to add a field (field id is 'numberTest') where I ask a mathematical sum, and I want the user to enter the correct answer e.g. 200. I know how to check if the field is empty, but how to I check if the user hasn't entered the correct number 200? Sorry if this is a really basic question!!

I tried:

```
if(!check_email_address($email)) {
    $errorMsg = "Please enter a valid email address";
} else if($numberTest != "200") {
    $errorMsg = "Your answer is incorrect";
} else {
    $errorMsg = "Please complete all fields";
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How do you check if its empty? You got your answer there ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple "if"

```
if ($_POST['number'] == 200){
    // OK do something
} else {
    // not 200
}
```

Comment: If user has not filled textbox then in `if` condition line, you get Notice: Undefined Index.

Comment: @RajivRanjan You have right but OP wrote:  I know how to check if the field is empty , but how to I check that the user had entered the exact number 200?

Comment: Hi Adam - thanks - this looks like the kind of thing. Can I check if it's not that number in a single line? i.e.  else if($numberTest ['number'] != 200) {

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following?

```
if(isset($_POST['numberTest'])) {
    if ($_POST['numberTest'] == 200) {
        echo "200";
    }
}
```

Note that it is PHP. PHP doesn't look to the data type. Which means that an integer can be written as an String or Character or the way around.